# How to compare two variables with creating your own function?

Tags: python

I need help with my homework I am doing coding for year 9. My teacher give me advance work because I know some about Python

I tried to measure the list and find the number inside the variable. Also I tried to turn the variable into integer and do maths.

That is what I have made so far I tried many ways to make the is_higher function to work.

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'


def is_higher(card1, card2):
   #I need to enter a function in here
return your_answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher('8D', '9S'))
  print(is_higher('2S', '2D'))
  print(is_higher('3H', '2H'))
  print(is_higher('QS', 'JS'))
  print(is_higher('AD', '2S'))
```

Comment: Can you explain the output you are expecting to get?

Comment: _"I tried to measure the list and find the number inside the variable. Also I tried to turn the variable into integer and do maths."_ I think that's a good approach. Did it work? Can you share the code where you tried these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: split the two-character string into *rank* and *suit* parts:

```
# this works because card1 and card2 are iterables (strings) with two elements each,
# so those two elements get split up when we do this
card1_rank, card1_suit = card1
card2_rank, card2_suit = card2
```

Next, find the index of the rank and suit inside your lists:

```
card1_score = (RANK_ORDER.find(card1_rank), SUIT_ORDER.find(card1_suit))
card2_score = (RANK_ORDER.find(card2_rank), SUIT_ORDER.find(card2_suit))
```

Note that I use a tuple for storing this information. When you compare two tuples to each other, the first elements get compared first, and if they're equal then the second elements get compared, and so on. In this case, suit will only be taken into account if rank is equal. So, to return the highest between `card1` or `card2` is higher, we can now do

```
if card1_score > card2_score:
    return card1
else:
    return card2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you onto the right track; I assumed suit order did not factor into determining which card is greater if it does; this should still provide you with the material to apply the ranking hierarchy to suit.

```
 RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
    SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'


def is_higher(card1, card2):
    if RANK_ORDER.find(card1[0]) > RANK_ORDER.find(card2[0]):
        your_answer = card1 +' is higher than ' + card2
    elif RANK_ORDER.find(card2[0]) > RANK_ORDER.find(card1[0]):
        your_answer = card2 +' is higher than ' + card1
    else:
        your_answer = card1 +' is equal to ' + card1
    return your_answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(is_higher('8D', '9S'))
    print(is_higher('2S', '2D'))
    print(is_higher('3H', '2H'))
    print(is_higher('QS', 'JS'))
    print(is_higher('AD', '2S'))
```

The output from the above should be:

```
9S is higher than 8D
2S is equal to 2S
2H is higher than 3H
QS is higher than JS
2S is higher than AD
```

For suit, you would compare using:

```
card1[1]
```

Rather than the 0th index which returns the rank or card value.